# Why did they halve their $\chi^2$ statistics in this article?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I was reading this [article](https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.2307/2657027) and tried to find their results regarding the $\chi^2$ tests displayed in table 2 on page 4. 
These are $\chi^2$ tests of data from the table 1 on page 3.
However I did not find the same results. For example, from the first line of Table 1 we have the data

```
Seed shape: Round (5474); Angular(1850)
```

And Mendel predicted a repartition of $3:1$, so probabilities of $( \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$. To test is the observed data are in agreement with this hypothesis we can compute a $\chi^2$ statistic.

Since $n=5474 + 1850 = 7324$ this statistic is (at least I thought it should be):
$$
\frac{(5474 - 0.75 \times 7324)^2}{0.75 \times 7324} + \frac{(1850 - 0.25 \times 6324)^2}{0.25 \times 7324}  = 0.2629
$$

However in the corresponding line in table 2 the actual value used is $0.1314$ which is preceiely half $0.2629$. 
And it is the same for the others $\chi^2$ statistics : they are half what I found.

My question is then : why did their values are half mines in their $\chi^2$ tests?

I think maybe it is because we are comparing observed proportion to true, fixed proportion instead of comparing two observed proportions and thus we need to divide the test statistic by two.

Comment: It shouldn't be because they are comparing to theoretical proportions.  That's a chi-square goodness-of-fit test, and it should agree with your values.  For your example, the following R code agrees with you.  `Observed = c(5474, 1850); Theoretical = c(0.75, 0.25); chisq.test(Observed, p=Theoretical)`

Comment: "However,the probability derived from a $\chi^2$ test is the probability of a deviation as great as or greater than the observed deviation in either direction from the expected value. Fisher’s calculation of a probability of one in 29 that Mendel would observe the deviation he did assumes a deviation of both the magnitude and in the direction he observed. This halves the probability to 0.0346, which corresponds closely to one in 29 trials." -- p. 740.  (This does not justify halving the $\chi^2$ statistic, but it at least hints at what the authors might have been thinking.)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the confusion.

It seems that it is an error and an [erratum](https://bsapubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.3732/ajb.89.1.176) was published on the website of the editor which contains:

> An error in the formula used to calculate the chi‐square values halved those values for the first seven entries in the original table; the corrected chi‐square values are twice those published. All other chi‐square values (entries 8–22) and their associated probabilities in Table 2 are correct.

Thank you and I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries.  Good sleuthing.  They should have had you proof their paper !